# Weird timing in loops

Tags: c, timing, any

So I was timing a function, and fell over a weird timing thing,

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long int time = 0, itrs = 100;

    struct timespec start, stop;

    for (int i = 0; i < itrs; i++) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

        f();

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
        time += stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }

    printf("%ld", time/itrs);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the loop a higher number of times, the function runs faster.

When i run it for instance 100 times, the function takes about 100 ns, but when i run 1000000 its about 40 ns.

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: 1. Startup overhead, 2. Your computer will be doing other things at the same time.

Comment: caching of values and code segments will shrink the amount of time needed to perform a function

Comment: Please post the contents of the `f()` function so we can evaluate the problem

Comment: have you checked to assure the variable `time` has not overflowed?

Comment: Have you checked that the other fields in the `struct timespec` have not incremented?